# Pandas: Count consecective True values within group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Ive found many similar questions answered, but they cant be used on a groupby, or they aren't looking for consecutive boolean values.

Im looking for a way (non-looping) to count the # of consecutive past TRUE values, on a group.

```
data = [
    [False, 'CLE',],
    [True, 'CLE'],
    [True, 'CLE'],
    [False, 'MON'],
    [False, 'MON'],
    [True, 'MON'],
    [True, 'CLE'],
    [False, 'CLE'],
    [False, 'CLE']
]
# Create the pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data,
                  columns=["a", "city"])
```

Desired Output:

```
0
1
2
0
0
1
3
0
0
```

I've been experimenting with:

```
df['x']=df.a.groupby((df.city!=df.city.shift()).apply(lambda x: x==True).cumsum()).cumcount()
```

Comment: `df.groupby('city')['bool'].apply(lambda x:x.eq(True).cumsum())`?

Comment: No once it hits a False, it needs to reset the consecutive count to 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To identify the consecutive `True` block, we can use `cumsum` on the `False`. Then we can groupby on these blocks:

```
blocks = (~df['a']).groupby(df['city']).cumsum()

output = df.groupby([blocks, 'city'])['a'].cumsum()
```

Output:

```
0    0
1    1
2    2
3    0
4    0
5    1
6    3
7    0
8    0
Name: a, dtype: int64
```